# I need checkboxes to save their state whn i go out of app or the activity

Tags: android

So i need checkboxes to save state when i exit or switch activity. I need many checkboxes, so I need a function that works for all the checkboxes.
please help.

Comment: When you say "exit", do you mean force close the app? Or just return to launcher and leave the app in the background?

Comment: I believe he/she means the latter! In which case, the OP should consider storing the last checkbox state onDestroy in preferences;

Comment: Force close, as in swipe it away from recent apps or what its called. But it also resets when i hit back and leave thr activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simple solution is to use SharedPreferences,
you can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

**Code**

create these 2 methods in your activity :

```
private void saveCheckboxesStates(){
SharedPreferences sharedPref =getActivity().getSharedPreferences("fileName",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);//replace fileName with any name you like 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
//suppose we have 3 checkboxes that we want to save their states
editor.putBoolean("checkbox1_state", checkBox1.isChecked()));
editor.putBoolean("checkbox2_state", checkBox2.isChecked()));
editor.putBoolean("checkbox3_state", checkBox3.isChecked()));
editor.apply();
```

}

```
private void loadCheckboxesStates(){
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("fileName",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);                  
boolean checkbox1State= sharedPref.getBoolean("checkbox1_state", false);
boolean checkbox2State= sharedPref.getBoolean("checkbox2_state", false);
boolean checkbox3State= sharedPref.getBoolean("checkbox3_state", false); 
checkBox1.setChecked(checkbox1State);
checkBox2.setChecked(checkbox2State);
checkBox3.setChecked(checkbox3State);
```

}

now override `onBackPressed` and `onDestroy` methods and call `saveCheckboxesStates` like that:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    saveCheckboxesStates();
}//this handle the case when the user clicks back the activity

@Override
public void onDestroy () {
    super.onDestroy();
    saveCheckboxesStates(); 
}//this handle the case when your app gets killed
```

then call the method `loadCheckboxesStates` in your `onCreate` method and you are done.